# Burnt candied pecans

Tags: nuts, burnt

I made a pound of candied pecans (egg white, brown sugar, vanilla...) and I guess I baked them too long.  They are good except for a burnt flavor and I was wondering if anyone knew of anything I can do to them now to salvage them... a coating or something?  I was considering brushing them with melted butter and sprinkling a sugar cinnamon mix on them... or dip half in chocolate?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut the pecans a bit smaller than whole, fry up a bunch of bacon, super crispy. Crumble that up and mix it in: meaty, protein-y snack, ... or sprinkle it on salads, veggies, and stuff. The bacon will set your senses up for a smokey burned flavor, and unless the pecans are *completely carbonized*, it'll taste great.